# The second ViewController in segmented container is under the navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

Hi I have this structure

The segmented container is `SDCSegmentedViewController`. The second `ViewController` is always under the `UINavigationBar` (like fullscreen) and I can't understand why.. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I have pushed an update to `SDCSegmentedViewController`. It was related to the `adjustsScrollViewInsets` property, which wouldn't work because the container view is not a scroll view. Now, if the first child of the container view is a scroll view, it gets adjusted like it does normally.

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets the updated SDCSegmentedViewController is throuing an exception on line [self updateBarsForViewController:self.viewControllers[self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex]];  because of the selectedSegmentIndex is -1

Answer (score 0):

Select the view controller and go to the inspector. Make sure that under Extend Edges checkboxes are not selected.

[image: Inspector]